# Calculate distance between two descriptors

Tags: c++, opencv, euclidean-distance, hamming-distance, feature-descriptor

I'm trying to calculate the distance (Euclidean or hamming) between two descriptors already calculated. The problem is I don't want to use a matcher, I just want to calculate the distance between two descriptors.
I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 and i have mine descriptors stored in a Mat type:

```
Mat descriptors1;
Mat descriptors2;
```

and now i just want to calculate the distance (preferably the Hamming distance since I'm using binary descriptors) between row1 of descriptors1 and row1 of descriptors2 (for example).

I have tried to use bitwise_xor() function but then I got not an effective way of doing the bitcount. There is no function to calculate the hamming distance between two arrays?

I notice that I'm fairly new to OpenCV but I appreciate any help. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use opencv's [norm](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#norm) function for this.

```
Mat descriptors1;
Mat descriptors2; 

double dist_l2  = norm(descriptors1,descriptors2,NORM_L2);      // l2 for surf,sift
double dist_ham = norm(descriptors1,descriptors2,NORM_HAMMING); // for ORB,BRIEF,etc.
```

Comment: The choice of norm may depend on how your descriptor is configured (e.g. ORB), see this answer: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/28560/28522.