# Calculating distance between SURF features in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, surf, euclidean-distance, descriptor

I want to be able to get a distance between SURF features in OpenCV. I'm using HDBSCAN to match multiple instance of an object in the image by clustering the features which requires calculating distances between the SURF descriptors. I know algorithms such as FLANN and Brute Force Matcher have to calculate such distance but after looking through the OpenCV code I could not find out how they do it. Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out a similar question has been asked and answered [Calculate distance between two descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26326252/calculate-distance-between-two-descriptors?rq=1). The answer provided there is correct.